# How to get and parse json answer from google translate

Tags: ajax, json, iframe, google-translate

I want to translate word with ajax request to google translate
If i use curl, it willl be like:

```
curl_init("http://translate.google.com/translate_a/t?client=t&text=hello&sl=en&tl=ru");
```

But i cant use server-side scripts with queries because they will be from same IP
But i cant use JSONP request too, because it's not allowed i think. Here's server response:

> [[["привет","hello","privet",""]],[["",["Алло","Здравствуйте."]],["имя существительное",["приветствие","приветственный возглас","возглас удивления"]],["глагол",["здороваться","звать","окликать"]],["междометие",["привет","здравствуйте","алло"]]],"en",,[["привет",[5],1,0,1000,0,1,0]],[["hello",4,,,""],["hello",5,[["привет",1000,1,0],["Здравствуй",0,1,0],["Здравствуйте",0,1,0],["Hello",0,1,0]],[[0,5]],"hello"]],,,[["en"]],13]

And i cant load content to iframe

```
<iframe src="http://translate.google.com/translate_a/t?client=t&text=hello&sl=en&tl=ru"></iframe>
```

because response content type is "text/javascript" and browser [downloads a file](http://jsfiddle.net/YnZ2u/)

PS. i cant decode content with php function json_decode() or with jquery.ajax because response json is corrupt. You can test it here http://json.parser.online.fr/

Give me an advice, please

Comment: suggestion:  (a) buy a license for a translation service that allows you to use "the same IP".  Or (b) don't do translations. The limits google places on the translation service are there for a reason. It seems you are looking for a way around those limits. Don't do that.

Comment: oh, god. It's experiment, i dont want to buy million-query license for one-day experiment.

Comment: Why are you bringing God into it?  If it's an experiment then you need not worry about the same ip issue.

Comment: Cheeso, i told about technical problem. Not moral or ethical. And i can't solve it, can you?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try:

```
http://translate.google.com/translate_a/t?client=p
```

if the client parameter is anything other than 't' it returns valid JSON data. Of course, you could always transform the 't' return variable into a valid array or JSON but this is easier.

Comment: Thank you, puromonogatari! I made this with transform way, but thanks for first solution

Comment: NP, it should be noted though that I had some trouble sending characters to it.... I couldn't find the reason but for some reason sending HTML entities works fine "&x281" for example, without the ";", try that if you have any encoding issues.

Comment: And it started using captcha

Comment: It seems this doesn't work anymore. Response is always an empty string now. May I please, ask how did you find out about this? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to add header param "User-Agent" = "Mozilla/4.0". Google adds captcha if you do not